# Unable to get HTTP POST parameters in `params` in scalatra

Tags: scala, http-post, scalatra

I am running `scalatra 2.2` using sbt version `0.13.0` and using its in-built server(jetty). I am running on kubuntu 13.10 64 bit and my java version `1.7.0_51`. I am using OpenJDK `64-Bit`. In my sample app i can get `GET` parameters through `params` but i cannot get `POST` parameters. I checked the `request.body` and it shows i am sending those parameters. 
My code for `GET` looks like this

```
get("/requests") {
    val typ = params.getOrElse("type", null)
    Map(
        "success" -> true,
        "respones" -> responses.get(typ)
      )
  }
```

This works.

My code for `POST` looks like this

```
post("/user/register") {
   val typ = params.getOrElse("type", null) // here typ is always null even when i send type as formdata
   if (typ == null) {
       halt(400, Map("type"-> typ, "body"-> request.body.toString))
   }
   // more code
}
```

This does not work. The response i get is

```
{"type":null,"body":"------WebKitFormBoundaryE05sRkwjtB4gBgSW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\nzombie\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryE05sRkwjtB4gBgSW--\r\n"}
```

So you see is that the parameter `type` is there in request body but null in `params`.
I also tried [this](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/tree/master/2.2/http/scalatra-http-demo) but i was unable to get `POST` requests to work. There is a github issue [here](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/issues/377)
Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the FileUploadSupport trait it will allow you to process multipart forms as your example shows a form boundary suggesting this is the issue.

An example inclusion:

```
import org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet
import org.scalatra.servlet.{FileUploadSupport, MultipartConfig, SizeConstraintExceededException}

class MyApp extends ScalatraServlet with FileUploadSupport {
  configureMultipartHandling(MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = Some(3*1024*1024)))
  // ...
}
```